# Digits after first dash on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

have a quick question
how I get all digits before first dash and just 6 after first dash.
example:

```
C14-043845-22    Result :C14-043845
C14P1-043846-21  Result :C14P1-043846
C14-043847-22    Result :C14-043847
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-') - 1) ||
       substr(col, instr(col, '-'), 7) as result
  from tbl
```

See demo -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed953/1/0